# How can i get StatusBar elements overlay over layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

[image]

I want layout like this for version above Android 4.0.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your theme, but it is only possible for API 19+ (4.4)

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: This screen shot is from Android 4.4

Comment: Right. That's the earliest it is possible.